# Parsing region code from php-world-cities-array

Tags: php, geonames

I have pulled Cities array from https://github.com/tapvt/php-world-cities-array. Each region is abbreviated except in case of US

```
array (
  'city' => 'Sant Julià de Lòria',
  'region' => '06',
  'country' => 'AD',
  'latitude' => '42.46372',
  'longitude' => '1.49129',
)
```

Since many countries have multiple cities with same name, I need to distinguish based on regions. In order to display region, I need something more than numbers to be recognised by users. For US, region comes in proper manner but for other countries like Germany, its numbers which is unfortunately not human readable.

My question is how can I get human readable names for regions in the php-world-cities-array?

Comment: You could make another array that translates the digits into their corresponding country name or simply search and replace. The file with all your arrays is pretty large. I'm not sure what you're using this data for, but perhaps it would be more advantageous to use an API instead.

Comment: I have made it into a db table for easy programmatic access. Parsing country name has been achieved but I could not figure out how to parse region numbers.

Comment: Region "02" for "München" in Germany - does "02" actually mean Bayern/Bavaria or whet is meant by "region". It could be as well a geographical region as well as an administrative region (federal state) or a postal region, which is different in all three cases. I wouldn't rely on that extremely large php array. Have a look at this, probably: http://planet.openstreetmap.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The region codes identify the administrative zones. For example, DE-01 identifies the Baden-Württemberg area, and here's the corresponding record:

```
  array (
    'city' => 'Stuttgart',
    'region' => '01',
    'country' => 'DE',
    'latitude' => '48.78232',
    'longitude' => '9.17702',
  )
```

To decipher Region Code 01 to Baden-Württemberg, you'll have to build another array. You may use a reverse geocoding service such as the Google Maps API. For example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=48.78232,9.17702&hl=en&sensor=false
```

This will give you all the names in each political administrative level. The Zone ID should be mapped to the province level, or "administrative_level_1". In the above example, this resolves to "Baden-Württemberg" or "BW" if you use the short_name field.

Remember to build an array as you decode the regions. Otherwise there will be too many duplicate requests to the Maps API and you'll get rate limited.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a go. How do i send the https request to fetch programattically?

Comment: I got the result programmatically. How would I get the value of short_name field in the recursive array. Also will the curl response in array or string?

Comment: set curl option to RETURNTRANSFER before executing. it'll return a JSON encoded string. use json_decode to convert that to an array